# Bypassing hiding Linux processes?

Tags: permissions, vulnerability

### Hiding Linux Processes

Recently, I've followed this [tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-hide-processes-from-other-users/), which detailed how to hide processes from users without `root` access, by means of setting `hidepid=n` on `/proc/`.

After following this tutorial step-by-step, I found that it is mostly effective at preventing a normal user from viewing other running processes(e.g. `htop`,`top`,`ps`).

### Bypass

From messing around, I have also found that I can bypass these restrictions on `/proc/` by using `loginctl` provided by `systemd`.

For example, if I were to run:

```
loginctl user-status root
```

I would be able to see all processes that the `root` user is running(that is if they are logged in)?

### Questions

So, my questions remain:

- Why is this allowed?
- How does this work(via direct `daemon`)?
- Is this a vulnerability

Comment: hidepid doesn't hide other evidence. systemd track its own process cgroup status. I don't think this is a vulnerability because it doesn't allow you access important property of root processes

Comment: @炸鱼薯条德里克  Why does systemd do this though?

Comment: Because it is designed to manage services and sessions using cgroup, which happens to let you see these processes. It's just a harmless side-effect

Comment: Then what's the point of even setting `hidepid`?

Comment: "it doesn't allow you access important property of root processes " Didn't I I just provide the answer?

Comment: since hidepid is mount option for procfs, it only applies to the info provided by the /proc filesystem. To answer your questions directly a) because you allowed it by accepting systemd ;-) b) systemd runs as root, has access to all the info, and decides what and how to share c) not really; and I'm skeptical about that hidepid option "hardening" your system at all.

Comment: I'll downvote your question for linking to some tutorial which doesn't have any useful info beyond that from the standard proc(5) manpage or the [Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/torvalds/linux/master/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt)

Comment: @UncleBilly Do you know of any way to prevent Systemd for displaying anything about process information

Comment: hmm, that's an amusing privacy-intruding feature from systemd.